# Qt, CMake и консольное окно

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake

Установил Qt 5.15.1. Создал простейший проект, состоящий из следующих трёх файлов:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    
    QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
    button.show();
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core gui widgets
CONFIG += c++11 
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

При сборке через `qmake`

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug && mingw32-make
```

всё нормально. Но при сборке через `cmake`

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug . && cmake --build .
```

при запуске программы появляется чёрное окошко консоли:
[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда это окошко берётся и как избежать его появления.

Answer (score 3):

Если посмотреть документацию на [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html), то станет очевидно, что `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)` создаёт *консольное* приложение. Чтобы создать приложение Windows с оконным интерфейсом, нужно эту строчку немного изменить:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Тебе надо добавить флаг при запуске команды `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mwindows"`

То есть в итоге: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug . && cmake --build . -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mwindows"`